# Slide in text on banner css animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to `translateX` text on the banner from left to right. I have taken a reference to animation from this site https://pereiraodell.com/

They are using jQuery/javaScript for animation. The same effect I want to have using CSS.

I am trying to replica same effect using CSS but mine was not as smooth as given in the reference.

In the referenced site, the text animation speed is gradually slowing down and the opacity setting works perfectly. I am not able to produce the same effect in my code. Maybe I am missing some breakpoints in keyframes. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5vax1uce/22/)

I want to show this animation on hover so that when the user hovers out, the text should go back to its original place in the animation.

```css
.banner{
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:green;
  border-radius:4px;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding-left:20px
}

.content{
  width:200px
}

.title{
  transform:translateX(-1000px);
  font-size:20px;
  color:#fff;
  padding-top:10px
}
.description{
  transform:translateX(-1000px);
  font-size:20px;
  color:#fff;
  padding-top:10px
}

.banner:hover .title{
  animation: slideInRight 1s;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards
}

.banner:hover .description{
  animation: slideInRight 1s 80ms;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards
}

@keyframes slideInRight {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50%{
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  80%{
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
<div class="content">
<div class="title">
  I am Title
</div>
<div class="description">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So after hovering, when the text appears, do you want the text to stay there or disappear as it is working currently?

Comment: @Code_Ninja I want to text stay there until the user hovers out

Answer (score 0):

**1st answer with animation**

```css
.banner {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 20px
}

.content {
  width: 200px
}

.title {
  transform: translateX(-1000px);
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  animation: slideOutLeft 1s 80ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards
}

.description {
  transform: translateX(-1000px);
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  animation: slideOutLeft 1s 80ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.banner:hover .title {
  animation: slideInRight 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards
}

.banner:hover .description {
  animation: slideInRight 1s 80ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards
}

@keyframes slideInRight {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes slideOutLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="title">
      I am Title
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**2nd answer with transition** gives better results

```css
.banner {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 20px
}

.content {
  width: 200px
}

.title {
  transform: translateX(-105%);
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

.description {
  transform: translateX(-105%);
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

.banner:hover .title,
.banner:hover .description {
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="title">
      I am Title
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Fiddle, Hope this solve your issue :)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5vax1uce/68/

```css
.banner {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 20px
}

.content {
  width: 200px;
}

.title {  
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100px);
  transition: all .8s linear;
}

.description {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100px);
  transition: all .8s linear;
}

.banner:hover .title {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.banner:hover .description {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
<div class="content">
<div class="title">
  I am Title
</div>
<div class="description">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
Here is the fix I have been talking about, I have applied the animation on the path `.banner .content .title` and `.banner .content .description`. I have edited your fiddle. I have made `.content` as `display:none` by default. When the `mouseenter` event is fired, the `.content` is changed to `display:block` and then the animation is applied. I hope it helps. I have updated the link to the fiddle.

```js
$(".banner").mouseenter(function(){
 $(".content").css("display","block");
});
```

```css
.banner{
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:green;
  border-radius:4px;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding-left:20px
}

.content{
  width:200px;
  display:none;
}

.title{
  transform:translateX(-1000px);
  font-size:20px;
  color:#fff;
  padding-top:10px
}
.description{
  transform:translateX(-1000px);
  font-size:20px;
  color:#fff;
  padding-top:10px
}

.banner .content .title{
  animation: slideInRight 1s;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
.banner .content .description{
  animation: slideInRight 1s;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

@keyframes slideInRight {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50%{
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  80%{
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="title">
      I am Title
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the link to your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5vax1uce/81/).

Comment: There has to be the delayed between animated elements. That's why I have added delay purposely

Comment: Okay let me try, I still new at CSS animation.

Comment: @Carlos Can I use jQuery to cover this situation of text staying right where it is?

Comment: I would love to see the CSS fix, however, you can use jQuery

Comment: I will try to apply the animation on `.banner:hover .content .title` and `.banner:hover .content .description` and make `.content` as `display:none` by default. If the banner is hovered, then `.content` will become `display:block`. Because when we hover, the changes are effecting that element till the pointer is on that element, after that they have to be reset. @Carlos

Comment: @Carlos please check the edit I have made to make answer. I hope this is the thing you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It was not working until inside the `css` script I did change the place of the `@keyframe slideInRight {}`, I put it before calling it then it worked for me.